# If XAML Grid Row/Column is "*" - How to get the usable area programmatically?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, grid, winrt-xaml

Below I have some rather raw code (test only, trying to prove this out).  I have a grid row and grid column who both have width and height respectively defined as "*" so that they use up all the usable space not used by the other rows/columns.  Pretty standard, or so I thought.

```
<Grid x:Name="PageContent" Background="{Binding PageColor}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="81" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="92" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button x:Name="backButton" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource TopBackButtonStyle}" />
    <Button x:Name="searchButton" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Click="GoSearch" Style="{StaticResource TopSearchButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <Button x:Name="settingsButton" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Click="GoSettings" Style="{StaticResource TopSettingsButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Name="MainScrollViewer" ZoomMode="Disabled" IsTabStop="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Padding="0,0,0,20" >
        <Image x:Name="PDFRenderedImage" AutomationProperties.Name="placeholder image" Source="Assets/placeholder-sdk.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Well now, I am trying to use some of the cheaper PDF display routines that Microsoft has defined for samples.  One of them is using RenderToStreamAsync with PdfPageRenderOptions.

One thing I want to do is try to scale the PDF resultant image so that the page fits on the screen no matter what.  But, to do so at least with the PdfPageRenderOptions means that I need to know the width/height ahead of time.

So, how can get, programatically, the width and height of a UIElement that is in a raw/column defined as "*" before that element is used (meaning, how can I get the usable area size even if that size isn't being used yet).

Does anyone see any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can always set the MinHieght and MinWidth if your area is not being used. That way it will default to the MinHeight and MinWidth and still be able to expand/contract accordingly.

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Add a name to your ScrollViewer, and then get it's Widht/Height properties in the code behind.

In Page.xaml

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScrollViewer">
    <Image.../>
</ScrollViewer>
```

In Page.xaml.cs

```
public void LoadPDF()
{
    var height = MyScrollViewer.Height;
    //do something with it
}
```

Comment: The scrollviewer in this case shows a height of NaN and ActualHeight of 0.  So both of these seem like a bust too.

Answer (score 0):

UIElement.ActualHeigh and ActualWeight are what I wanted.  But still not fully.

What I ended up doing is messy and I don't like it.  What I do is render and display the PDF as an Image.  Then read the Actualheight and ActualWidth and re-render the whole thing again using those (the viewable) dimensions that were used.

It works, it seems heavy but it does work.

Comment: Actually no, that still doesn't work.  That gives the acutal height and width of the image used for prototyping only.

Answer (score 0):

Just give a `x:Name` to your specific row/column, than query their `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` respectively. (If you really want to make sure that this happens after the rendering phase, do all this by `Dispatcher.Invoke` with a **low** priority setting.)